# Laravel - Why pass the return value in an anonymous array?

Tags: php, laravel

In a new project I just checked out, I noticed the following lines of code. I wonder why you pass the return value of the request object into an anonymous array.

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    ['entity' => $entity] = $request->validate([
        'entity' => ['required', new ValidSomething()],
    ]);

    $paginator = SomeModel::query()
        ->when($entity, fn($q) => $q->where('entity', $entity))
        ->paginate(10);
}
```

I was also not aware until just now that this also works. It would have been sufficient to assign it directly in `$entity`.

Comment: `$request->validate()` returns an Array of validated values, like `['entity' => 'valid value']`, and `['entity' => $entity] = $request->validate(...)` generates the variable `$entity`, which has the value of `'valid value'`. Typical syntax is `$validated = $request->validate(...)`, then `$validated['entity']`, but this is simply short-hand/array destructuring (I think that's the right word here).

Comment: It is as Tim Lewis says. Another equivalent way of doing this would be `$entity = $request->validate(['entity' => [...]])['entity'];`

Comment: And here's a quick example: https://3v4l.org/1vL6L. I actually hadn't seen this syntax either until recently, but it's an interesting way of defining variables from array indices, but there are other approaches that are a little less confusing. It really boils down to needing individual variables for each (or specific) array indices (like `$entity`), or simply using them as needed (like `$validated['entity']`), etc.

Comment: @TimLewis and IGP ! Thanks. I have to get used to it. But to be honest it's not really a nice destructing like in javascript  way and I find the old notation more pleasant and self-explanatory. What do you think?

Comment: I think it's nice to have this as an option, but it feels too clever for it's own good, and again, why not just `$validated = $request->valiate()`, then `$validated['entity']`? The times you'd need a variable for each (or again, a subset of) array index feels few and far between. And yes, JS's implementation is a lot cleaner and I personally use it _a lot_ (i.e. `const { entity, another } = validated;`). By that's my opinion 